# Dynamic arrays spill horizontally

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I just discovered the dynamic array in the latest version of Excel and this is a huge improvement.

Still I would like to "spill" horizontally, not vertically. Is this possible ?

Comment: Use transpose or make the input array horizontal.

Comment: good point. 1/ actually making the input array horizontal is no option since I get the matrix externally from excel (jedox formula, e.g. PALO.ELEMENT_GET_CHILDREN) 2/ transpose implies that I have the data already in the sheet, and refer to point 1. BUT! combining both works like a charm: =TRANSPOSE(PALO.ELEMENT_GET_CHILDREN)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the spill function in the TRANSPOSE function.

In the image below, the data is in A2:A8.

In B2 the formula is `=SORT(A2:A8)` this results in the vertical spill matching the vertical nature of the data.

To see the same result horizontally see the spill in C2:I2.  The function in C2 is `=TRANSPOSE(SORT(A2:A8))`

[image: Example of the TRANSPOSE function with a spill]

If you want to use the horizontal list in a data validation, simply use `=C2#` as the source for the list.

[image: Data Validation Screenshot]

As shown in the screenshot below, the cell `K5` has the validation shown in the screenshot above.

[image]

Comment: How can we then use this horizontally-spilled array in a validation list? If the array starts at B2, with a normal one I would use =B2# for the validation list, but with what would we replace the `#` if it is horizontal instead of vertical?

Comment: @GerardReches, I just edited the answer above to address your question. Just use `=C2#`